# Write an image to an external hard disk in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, imaging, disk-image, raw-disk

As you may already know, Windows Vista SP2 and up (includes Windows 7) block raw disk write access. Is there a way, short of patching the kernel, to override that block? So in cygwin I can do e.g. `cat ./myfile>/dev/sdc3`

Is there a Windows freeware program that you recommend which writes raw images to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be making raw sector-for-sector images of NTFS. The [ImageX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145(WS.10).aspx) utility from the Windows Automated Installation Kit (AIK) will do what you're looking for, albeit to image a machine while it's running you'll need to use Volume Shadow Copy to make a snapshot and image the snapshot (somebody has written [a crafty little script](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Taking-an-image-of-a-remote-machine-whilst-it39s-running-m85827.aspx) to do this but I've never tried it, personally).

Edit:

If you're imaging from Linux consider using the `ntfsclone` tool from the [ntfsprogs](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ntfsprogs.htm) suite. I've used it for years with great success.

Comment: this won't help me image windows from a Linux disc, then copy it back over, however.

Comment: I'll drop on an edit.

Answer (score -1):

[dd for windows?](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)  If you're trying to backup/restore a partition, I'd suggest something like Clonezilla instead.  It's going to be a lot more reliable if you can boot the system to another OS before trying to image it.  Taking a raw image of a running system may or may not work correctly.

Comment: Also, dd for Windows mentions Windows XP but makes no mention of working on Windows Vista and later (which usually requires a kernel driver)